# What does the Maven verify command do?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, verify

It says in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)
that the verify phase in the build lifecycle

> run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure quality criteria are met

What does this exactly mean?

Answer (score 13):

The `verify` phase will indeed verify the integration tests results, if one or more results have failed or not.

### **How can you run those tests in your Maven?**

Usually the [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) is used to orchestrate the lifecycle of the integration tests, it has two goals:

1. [failsafe:integration-test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) runs the integration tests of an
   application.
2. [failsafe:verify](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html) verifies that the integration tests of an
   application passed.

In the case of the verify goal, as per documentation:

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: verify.

In the [usage section of the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) you can check some more discussion around the verify for each testing provider it is available

For this particular piece of configuration, the verify will check if some of summary files have any failures:

```
<execution> 
  <id>verify</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>verify</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <summaryFiles>
      <summaryFile>target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-red-bevels.xml</summaryFile>
      <summaryFile>target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-no-bevels.xml</summaryFile>
    </summaryFiles>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

**Edit 1**

Some interesting article can be found in [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/integration-testing-with-maven/) around the maven configuration for this.